# iOS6: MFMailComposeViewController is not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

MFMailComposeViewController  not presenting in ios6  where as same code is working in ios6
 and my code is

```
   if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
   {
       searchView.hidden=YES;
       MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
       picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
       [picker setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Query from ccc App"]];
       NSArray *toarr =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ccc-connections@ccc.edu", nil];
       [picker setToRecipients:toarr];
       [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];          
   }
```

Comment: Are you running this on a device with a mail account?

Answer (score 1):

`presentModalViewController:animated:` is Deprecated in iOS 6.0.

Use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitel];
[mc setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
[mc setToRecipients:empfaenger];

[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

switch (result) {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Email cancelled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Email failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Email saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Email sent");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}